# Set the visibility of a button inside Telerik RadGrid Group Header

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a button inside the group header but I only want to display it if at a Bool is true for at least 1 of the items in the group.

I tried the `OnDataBound` Event for the grid and looped across all items to see if the bool was true/false. The problem is I am not sure how to get the relevant group header then and set the visibility of the button.

```
protected void RadGrid2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid2.Items)
    {
        bool Mismatch = Convert.ToBoolean(item.GetDataKeyValue("IsMismatch"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void RadGrid2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid2.Items)
    {
      Button GroupheaderBtn = (Button)Item.FindControl("headerbotton");//find button Group header button
      bool Mismatch = Convert.ToBoolean(item.GetDataKeyValue("IsMismatch"));
    }
}
```